# Adding a subview without a XIB

Tags: cocoa-touch, xcode, ios, uiview, addsubview

This may seem painfully simple, but I'm just starting out so bear with me...

I have a main view with a toolbar. When the user presses a button in the toolbar, I would like a small prompt to appear at the top of the screen. I added a UIView within the existing UIView, and set it to be hidden. I connected that to an ivar called 'searchView' in my view controller, and tried the following:

```
searchView.hidden = NO;
```

When that didn't work I tried adding...

```
[self.view addSubview:self.searchView];
```

...which didn't work either.

Do I need to set the index somehow to bring it above the main view?

Is this approach just altogether wrong?

Comment: so searchView *does* exist in your XIB?

Answer (score 1):

If you created the UIView from the interface builder, forget to use addSubview because interface builder it's doing this automatically.

To do that in graphical mode (IB), follow this steps:

Define an IBOutlet in your file "h" should be something like:

```
IBOutlet UIView * myHiddenView;
```

Then in IB, connect the IBOutlet that you have defined in the h file to the UIView that you have created graphically in the IB and give the hidden property to this UIView (checkbox).

Then in your button press method do this:

myHiddenView.hidden = NO;

If you prefer do it programmatically to copy this example code:

define in the interface of the .h file

```
UIView *myHiddenView;
```

after the interface in the .h file:

```
-(void)displayView:(id)sender;
```

then in the .m file:

```
-(void)viewDidLoad{
    myHiddenView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame: CGRectMake (x, y, width, height)];
    myHiddenView.hidden = YES;
    [self.view addSubview: myHiddenView]

    UIButton *button = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(x, y, width, height)];
    [button setTitle:@"button" forState:(UIControlState)normal];
    [button addTarget: self action: @selector(displayView:) forControlEvents: UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [self.view addSubview:button];
}

-(void)displayView:(id)sender{
    myHiddenView.hidden = NO;
}
```

Comment: For some reason these still don't work with my original project. If I make a new one with two nice, neat views, it works great, but there must be something weird about the classes I was using. Thank you anyway!